# UITableView either not being called even though I have set its delegate, dataSource, and registered the reusable cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, delegates

So I have a `UITableView` (not a tableView controller), and I have set its `delegate`, `dataSource`, and even registered its reusable cell, in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
searchTableView.delegate = self
searchTableView.dataSource = self
searchTableView.isHidden = true
searchTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
searchTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResultCell")
```

Don't worry about the `isUserInteractionEnabled`, I change that to `true` when the user is supposed to be able to use it. Anyway, I am 100% sure that the prototype cell has the correct Reuse Identifier in the storyboard as well as my `cellForRowAt` function. Here are the table view `dataSource` functions:

```
//MARK: - UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource Methods

extension MapViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.searchTextField.text!
        let completionResults = searchCompleter.results
        print("Yo")
        return completionResults.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.searchTextField.text!
        let completionResults = searchCompleter.results
        print(completionResults)
        print("yo")
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchResultCell", for: indexPath)
    
        cell.textLabel?.text = completionResults[indexPath.row].subtitle
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

Yet nothing is populating the tableView when I am in the simulator. I think the tableView `dataSource` functions are just not being called, because I set print statements in them and they do not appear.  I am also 100% sure that `completionResults` (an `MKLocalSearchCompleter`) does work, as I use it at the same time, in my searchBar `textDidChange` function and it prints results. I don't see why it would work in that function, and not my tableview ones, unless it does HAVE to be in a searchBar function. Anyway, just in case that matters, here's that function:

```
//MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate Methods

extension MapViewController: UISearchBarDelegate, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        if searchText.count > 0 {
            searchTableView.isHidden = false
            searchTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else {
            searchTableView.isHidden = true
            searchTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    
        searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.searchTextField.text!
        let completionResults = searchCompleter.results
        print(completionResults) 
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why my `searchTableView` won't call the `dataSource` functions? Someone even suggested that it was constraints at one point, and I have made sure that those are correct, so that isn't a problem either. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t appear to be calling `searchTableView.reloadData()`. It won’t reload the table unless you call that method.

Generally you’d set a delegate for the `MKLocalSearchCompleter` and call `reloadData` in [`completerDidUpdateResults(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleterdelegate/1452209-completerdidupdateresults).